# is there a suggested "best" location for a global .vim dir

Tags: vim, xubuntu

I am setting up a single pc running xubuntu which several people will use. Although I may well be the only one who uses vim, rather than install a .vim dir in each user's ~ is there a better path the folder can be stored and so loaded whenever vim is fired up no matter on which user's account?

I found lots of advice regarding a global .vimrc file but next to nothing regarding a global .vim dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try `help VIMDIR` then you could see that the command `:version` gives you the path you're after. Apparently this is set at compile time.

On my machine "osx" it set to "/usr/share/vim"

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 24 2013 18:58:47)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments -conceal +cryptv
+cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer
+fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse
-mouseshape -mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl
+persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn -python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline
-sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
```

Answer (score 1):

That path has to satisfy two requirements:

- it must already be in `'runtimepath'` so that the configuration is picked up by default, i.e. without individual users having to modify their `~/.vimrc`
- it must not be occupied by files that ship with Vim, so that you don't run into problems when updating

On my Ubuntu 13.10, there's `/usr/share/vim/vim74`, which contains Vim's runtime (so off-limits), and the `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`, which is symlinked to `/etc/vim`. I'd suggest putting global plugins into the latter, i.e. `/etc/vim/plugin/`.